# adding data to a date field attached to a node in drupal 7

Tags: date, drupal-7, data-migration, drupal-field-api

I need to add data to a datetime field in drupal 7. I am tryin to use

```
$node->field_test_a_updated[0]['value'] = $val;
$node->field_test_a_updated[0]['delta'] = 0;
$node->field_test_a_updated[0]['timezone'] = 'UTC';
$node->field_test_a_updated[0]['timezone_db'] = 'UTC';
$node->field_test_a_updated[0]['date_type'] = 'datetime';
```

where $val has the value "2010-06-15T00:00:00-00:00".

When i try to import the content, all the other fields attached to the node get migrated properly, except the date field.I have also tried using [LANGUAGE_NONE] option.

I am sure i am missing out something that is related to drupal7 field api.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of fields in Drupal 7 (in this context) is:

```
array(
  'language_code' => array(
    0 => array(
      'value => $val,
      'other_column_value' => $other_val
    )
  )
);
```

The `delta` is handled by the key of each of the arrays inside `$array['language_code']` so you don't need to include it. In your case you want the code to look like this (assuming of course you're passing the node through `node_save()` afterwards):

```
$node->field_test_a_updated[LANGUAGE_NONE] = array(
  0 => array(
    'value' => $val,
    'timezone' => 'UTC',
    'timezone_db' => 'UTC',
    'date_type' => 'datetime'
  )
);
```

Hope that helps